# Select values that are NOT in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

Let's say I have three values in PHP: "a", "b", "c". Doesn't matter whether in an array or comma separated string.
There is a table in database:

```
id | value  
1  | a  
2  | b  
3  | d
```

My purpose is to find the values that are in php array but not in database table.
The given example will give "c".
Can I do it with only one query?

**UPDATE**

Received several good suggestions in answers about array_diff(), though in my case the DB table is really large and the array has not more than 5-6 items. So it would be better to perform 5-6 queries, I think.

Comment: Do you _really_ have to do it with a SQL query?

Comment: I prefer to. And was wondering if it is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the PHP array is short, you can build a `UNION ALL` query to build your *small* table, then use `NOT IN` or `LEFT JOIN` query (whichever is faster) against the *large* table:

```sql
SELECT value
FROM (
    SELECT 'a' AS value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'c'
) AS php_array_values
WHERE value NOT IN (
    SELECT value
    FROM that_large_table
);
```

Alternately, you can insert the php array values in a temporary table and use the `IN`  or `JOIN` queries. Of course, this means you end up writing three extra queries:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS php_array_values (value VARCHAR(100));

DELETE FROM php_array_values;

INSERT INTO php_array_values VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c');

SELECT php_array_values.value
FROM php_array_values
LEFT JOIN that_large_table ON php_array_values.value = that_large_table.value
WHERE that_large_table.value IS NULL
```

Comment: I particularly like the first solution!

Comment: @Bangline: NB. `NOT IN` is a potential slowness inducing operator.

Comment: @nick: you're right. The `LEFT JOIN` query shown in example 2 will work with both examples.

Answer (score 2):

how about this?

```php
<?php
    $a = array('a', 'b', 'c');
    $values = implode("','", $a);
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `value` FROM `mytable` WHERE `value` IN ('$values')";
    echo $sql;
```

perform the sql query. the result will be those 0 to 3 elements you already have. next, do an array_diff (which will not be heavy at all, since you'll have your initial small array, and the array of those in the db, which is even smaller).

```php
$not_in_db = array_diff($a, $array_from_sql_result);
```

if what you have is a string with comma separated values, then you'll need to "explode" it first:

```php
$s = "a,b,c";
$a = explode(",", $s);
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your answer is an opposite task (select values from table that are not in array)

Comment: @lvil oh... thanks! i totally got it backwards. all better now :)

Answer (score 0):

You could select all the entries in the table and then perform an `array_diff()`.

But this isn't one query, is one query and some post processing.

Answer (score 0):

For this I would pull values from the table into an array and use `array_diff`

REF: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: Thank you. A good suggestion, though in my case the DB table is really large and the array has not more than 5-6 items. So it would be better to perform 5-6 queries, I think.

Comment: Fair enough I was thinking it could be a bit heavy if the table was really large. Preforming a diff on said data would be totally inefficient. It certainly sounds like performing the 5-6 queries would be more appropriate unless a SQL guru on here comes up with something.

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(*) as count from tablename 
where field1 != $arr[0] && field2 != $arr[1] && field3 != $arr[2];
```

You can use and or or operators if you want. if the return count for this query is 0 then the array values are not exist in the database already.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pulling all the elements from the DB you can try using 'LIKE' statement, this will reduce the number of entries pulled from DB.

something like this :

PHP array values :  a,b,c

DB values : a,b,d

```
select value from your_table_name where (value LIKE '%a%') OR (value LIKE '%b%') OR (value LIKE '%c%');
```

o/p of this will be : {a,b}

now use **array_diff** of php.