# Mysql Array no results found

Tags: php, mysql

Need your help with my PHP/MYSQL array.

I have a php script that selects users from a string like this:
email@email.com, email@email2.com, email@email3.com

I have a MYSQL database where some registrated users are present with their email adresses.
The script needs to check if the email adress is present in the rows like this:

```
$splitdata = for example: email@email.com, email@email2.com, email@email3.com

$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` IN ('".join("','", $splitdata)."')") or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());
```

Then i get the result with a MYSQL fetch array:

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {      
$email = $result['email'];
```

For the results i insert a value in another table. But only for the email adresses that could be found in de rows.

**What i need:**

I want to send an email to the email adresses of the users that were not found in the table. For an invite to the software.  It now only works with users that could be found, but i need  to do a different action to who couldn't be found.

It does not have to be in the same MYSQL fetch, i can create another mysql fetch for all the email adresses that could not be found in the database. I need some example code or somebody who know how to do this.

Currently have tried NOT IN but it gave me a result of every user in the list except the ones that could be found. The result must be the email adresses that could not be found.

Comment: (a) MySQL doesn't have arrays. (b) MySQL and PHP are completely unrelated technologies...

Comment: The mysql extension is outdated and on its way to deprecation. New code should use mysqli or PDO, both of which have important advantages, such as support for prepared statements. Don't use [`or die`](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die) when outputting HTML. You'll get invalid HTML.

Comment: Outputting database error messages to non-admin users [discloses too much information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995351.aspx#securityerrormessages_topic2). Instead, log the MySQL error message. For some errors (such as those related to missing or invalid values), output your own [error message](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Windows/Windows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-TP10) to the user and what action the user can take to address it. For the rest, inform the user that there was an internal error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select values that are NOT in table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832465/select-values-that-are-not-in-table)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `NOT IN` instead of `IN`?

Comment: Like this?         $sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` NOT IN ('".join("','", $splitdata)."')") or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());
            while($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {  
      $finalemail = $result['email'];

Answer (score 0):

So basically you are looking for all users that are not in your `$splitdata`

Have you tried `NOT IN`?

```
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` NOT IN ('".join("','", $splitdata)."')") or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());
```

Comment: Currently have tried NOT IN but it gave me a result of every user in the list except the ones that could be found. The result must be the email adresses that could not be found.